# Networkx - Katz centrality in projected graphs

Tags: networkx, eigenvalue, node-centrality

I have the following bipartite network image I'm trying to reproduce:

[image]

I tried:

```
bi_graph = nx.Graph()
bi_graph.add_edges_from([(1,"a"), (2,"a"), (2,"b"), (3,"a"), (3,"b"), (4,"b"), (4,"c"), (5,"b"), (5,"d"), (6,"c"), (6,"d"), (7, "d")])
pos = nx.bipartite_layout(bi_graph, nodes= [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
nx.draw(bi_graph, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_color='pink')
plt.title('rede bipartida')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Now I need to make two graph projections:

one for the letters

```
projection_letters = nx.bipartite.projected_graph(bi_graph, ["a", "b", "c", "d"])

nx.draw(projection_letters, with_labels=True, node_color='gray')
plt.title('projeção (vértices do tipo letras)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

one for the numbers

```
projection_numbers = nx.bipartite.projected_graph(bi_graph, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])

nx.draw(projection_numbers, with_labels=True, node_color='pink')
plt.title('projeção (vértices do tipo número)')
plt.show()
```

[image]

---

Finally I need to calculate 2 things:

-katz centrality for `projection_numbers` and find lowest and highest node values for `alpha=0.15`, like so:

```
print('Katz:')
alpha = 0.15
for node, val in nx.katz_centrality(projection_numbers,alpha=alpha).items():
    print("%s %.2f" % (node, val))
```

which prints:

```
1 0.29 (low)
2 0.41
3 0.41
4 0.41
5 0.45 (high)
6 0.35
7 0.29
```

I though low and high would be nodes 1 and 5, but I'm getting this answer as wrong..

---

-Calculate the highest alpha value for `projection_letters`, which I'm told is the inverse of the highest engeinvalue.

How do I calculate this top `alpha`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the maximum alpha value, you would first need to compute the eigenvalues of the adjacency matrix of your `projection_letters` graph (see more info [here](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.katz_centrality.html)) and then compute the inverse of the max absolute eigenvalue.

You can extract the set of eigenvalues with `nx.adjacency_spectrum` ([doc](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.linalg.spectrum.adjacency_spectrum.html#networkx.linalg.spectrum.adjacency_spectrum)).

See full code below:

```py
adj_mat_proj_letters_spec=nx.adjacency_spectrum(projection_letters) 
alpha_max=1/np.amax(np.abs(adj_mat_proj_letters_spec))
print('Max alpha: ' +str(alpha_max))
```

And the output returns:

`Max alpha: 0.460811127189111`

Comment: perfect! thanks do you reckon the kats centrality calculation is right?

Comment: I imagine it's probably right, based on the docs. One thing you could do to verify that it makes sense is to compare your results with the ones given by `nx.eigenvector_centrality`.  According to [this](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.katz_centrality.html), Katz centrality is a a generalization of eigenvector centrality so the two methods should give you similar results.